# VS2008 I can't compile if I add reference to OpenNETCF.Net.Mail (added details)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, opennetcf

I need to send mail from a Windows Embedded Compact 7 device and I'm trying to use OpenNETCF.Net.Mail.

My project is in VB.NET, CF3.5 and when I add OpenNETCF.Net.Mail to the project references the building fails (without adding a single line of code related to that library).

I have added also OpenNETCF, OpenNETCF.Net and OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms without any problem.

I get no error in the output log, just at the end the word FAILED...

I have never used OpenNETCF before so I apologize if my error is trivial but I couldn't find any solution.

To get this problem it is enough to create a new SmartDevice project (VB.NET, CF3.5) and in the property of the project to add a reference to OpenNETCF.Net.Mail.dll: the project doesn't compile any more.
I just get a warning about a version conflict:

```
Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac, Retargetable=Yes" from Version "2.0.0.0" [] to Version "3.5.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.
```

Searching info about that warning I found that it is "safe" to ignore it because the OpenNETCF version that I'm using (2.3.12004.0) is compatible with CF3.5.

If I remove the reference to OpenNETCF.Net.Mail.dll and I add a reference to OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.dll I get 5 warnings about remapping but the project compiles.

Anyone has a suggestion to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Steve

---

Hi,
it seems that this topic is not very interesting but I've found the solution and I want to share it.

I contacted OpenNETCF support and Chris Tacke answered very kindly.

The solution is to remove from project references `System.Xml.Linq` that for some reason sometimes generates this kind of problem in VB.NET CF 3.5 projects.

Comment: Please add some code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: @rayryeng - thanks for your interest, I added detail to the post